# How to parsing a file in Python starting from a line containing specific string

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re

with open('dio.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        y = re.match('^Value   Node', line)
        if y:
         next
        line = line.rstrip()
        x = re.match('(^\d+)', line)
        print(x)
```

The file (dio.txt) contains the following data

fgetip:
get the maximum value of the test
45th value is max
7176    80PGP42
8656    18PxP00
.....
logfile is not save

*Value   Node     State      Code
7724    79G7P42             TTP7R_MxT72   Test-Failed

7729    79M7M7S             TTP7R_MxT74   Test-Failed

77G2P72             TTP7R_MxT75   Test-Failed

79G7P22             TTP7R_MxT77   Test-Failed

7760    78D07A7             TTP7R_MxT77   Test-Failed

7763    78D07B3   UNAVA     TTP7R_CxT79   Test-Failed

7775    77A2I7R             TTP7R_CxT75   Test-Failed

77A2I2R             TTP7R_CxT73   Test-Failed

77A0I3R             TTP7R_CxT76   Test-Failed

74A7I4R   AVA       TTP7R_CxT74   Test-Passed

7646    77R2G7M   UNAVA     TTP7R_CxT78   Test-Passed

7648    77R2G2M             TTP7R_CxT74   Test-Passed

7973    77C2M7S             TTP7R_CxT79   Test-Passed
End*

40th value is min
7176    80zGP49
8656    1zP1P11

1. I need to code to start looking for the line
   Value   Node     State      Code
   then go to the next line and start apply the code. But it doesn't work
2. I need the code to do parsing (Only etween the lines) starting after the line
   Value   Node     State      Code
   and ending on the line
   END

3)( I tried to format the input above, but i couldn't. How can I format the input data?)

Comment: Did the answer work for you as expected?

Comment: @lllrnr101 the answer is working for 2nd case . For the query No.1 "start looking for the line Value Node State Code then go to the next line and start apply the code" (Without checking the "End"). Also, the code looks long, I'm new in Python, but comparing to Awk , in Awk we can do it in one line.

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand. Do you mean it does the processs the line where Value Node State Code starts?

Comment: @lllrnr101 Now your code is working to parsing in the file (Startswith -- > till Endswith). But if I need only to parse from Startswith till the end of the file, I tried to modify the code and it doesn't work. Can you support.

Comment: You can comment out the endswith condition which resets the start_parsing variable. Then you will always be in start parsing mode.

Comment: It work now . Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [endwiths](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) built-in methods.

```
start_parsing = False
with open('dio.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('Value Node State Code'):
            start_parsing = True
            continue # if you want to move to next line wihtout parsing information in this line
        if line.endswith('End'):
            start_parsing = False         
        if start_parsing:
            # Put your parsing logic here
```